# Find all 3-digit numbers divisible by a sum of groups of its digits

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility, decimal-expansion

How to find all three-digit number which are divisible by a sum of specific digit groups explained below?

The original number should have only non-zero and non-repeating digits.

example:
$301$ has a zero digit - cannot be used
$331$ does not have different digits - cannot be used

And the number should be divisible by two-digit group of its own digits, which are made by omitting one of the number's digits.

example:
$785$ should be divisible by $78$, $75$, and $85$.

I have come just to this:

If the number is made of digits $a, b, c$ like this $[abc]$, the number should be divisible by
$(10a + b) + (10b + c) + (10a + c) = 20a + 11b + 2c$

But I am not sure how to find all of the suitable numbers.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Have you found any?  If there are none, there might be a simple argument to see that.  If there are some, then I expect a simple search is the easiest way to go.

Comment: How do you get from being divisible by $78$, $75$, and $85$ to a need for being divisible by $78+75+85=238$?

Comment: Note:  $150,240,360$ work so I think a full search is needed.  Happily, it's not difficult.

Comment: @lulu, the OP specified *non*zero digits.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Ah, good point.  Though I am skeptical that a sensible argument exists which will include all the conditions.  A search only takes a few minutes.

Comment: @lulu, agreed.  I think it'd be OK to relax the nonzero and nonrepeating restrictions (except for repeated $0$s), find all *those* solutions, and show they all have $0$s and/or repeated digits, e.g. $110$.

Comment: @BarryCipra I'll look into that then, thanks

Comment: Note:  in the header you ask that you number be divisible by the sum of the three two digit numbers, but in the body you just mention divisibility by each of the three digit numbers ("example:
785 should be divisible by 78, 75, and 85.")  You should clarify the question.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080359/find-all-three-digit-numbers-which-are-divisible-by-groups-of-its-digits/3080367#3080367

Comment: @lulu Seems that "divisible by the sum" is meant, but it is not written down in a consistent way.

Comment: @Peter  I guess, though I don't understand why the OP doesn't just clarify the point.

Comment: @lulu How can $240$ and $360$ be solutions ? Or didn't you mean the sum ?

Comment: @Peter  I was looking at the question in the body of the post.  $240$ is divisible by each of $20,24,40$.  there are other examples, but they all contain a $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The following PARI/GP program finds the $4$ solutions , if we only demand that the number is divisible by the sum of the three numbers :

```
? for(a=1,9,for(b=0,9,for(c=0,9,if(Mod(100*a+10*b+c,20*a+11*b+2*c)==0,if(a*b*c<>
0,if(length(Set([a,b,c]))==3,print([a,b,c])))))))
[1, 3, 8]
[2, 9, 4]
[3, 5, 1]
[4, 5, 9]
?
```

Comment: If we allow zeros, $108 $ and $150$ are further solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this contribution! But isn't there a way to do this by hand according to some formula or so? Programming it is of course an easy way to solve this problem :D